# Unable to find GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV define on Android GLES

Tags: android, opengl-es, game-development, game-engine, gles

I'm currently working on an Android project that involves OpenGL ES development. However, I've encountered an issue where I can't seem to find the definition for GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV when working with GLES on Android.

This definition is particularly useful for normal and tangent vertex storing due to its compact representation.

Is this define supposed to be available on Android GLES? If so, where can I find its definition or documentation? If not, what alternative approach should I consider for achieving the same functionality?

Any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Checked the GLES headers included in my project, but couldn't locate the definition.
Searched through the Android NDK documentation and OpenGL ES specifications but couldn't find any mention of GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL ES 2.0 does not support `GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` as vertex attribute data format, the definition of `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV_EXT` you found in `GLES2/gl2ext.h` is defined in extension [`GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV.txt) and is valid only as texture type for `TexImage2D` or `TexImage3D` when this extension is available.

However, OpenGL ES 2.0 with extension [`GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2.txt) supports `GL_UNSIGNED_INT_10_10_10_2_OES` and `GL_INT_10_10_10_2_OES` vertex attribute data formats, so it can be used, if you can change packing of values.

Still, support in OpenGL ES 2.0 requires some work to check extensions and some devices may not support required extensions. Because formats are supported only with extensions, their definitions are found in `GLES2/gl2ext.h`

OpenGL ES 3.0 supports `GL_INT_2_10_10_10_REV` vertex attribute data format (also it's supported as texture data type) in basic specification, so it can be used for any devices with support of OpenGL ES 3.0 and its definition can be found in `GLES3/gl3.h` in NDK.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the definition under GLES3\gl3.h

However, at the documentation [here](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.1/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) I understand it should support this flag also at api 2.0.

I have also find the GL_UNSIGNED_INT_2_10_10_10_REV_EXT definition under GLES2\gl2ext.h

I hope it would be safe use that flag on api 2.0 too.

Comment: GLES 3 is ~10 years old now, so should be ubiquitous on Android. No need to limit yourself to 2.0.